# The first iteration of nested loops does not iterate till last element

Tags: python, list

I need to print the largest contiguous sum of elements in list. The answer is correct if it is in any iteration other than the first iteration.

```
n = int(input())

s = input()
s = s.split()
u = []
print(s)


for i in range(0, n):
    sum = s[i]
    for j in range(i, n-1):

        if int(s[j]) + int(s[j+1]) >= int(sum):
            sum = int(sum) + int(s[j+1])
            print(s[j], s[j+1])
            print(int(sum))
        else:
            u.append(int(sum))
            break

u.sort()
print(u[-1])
```

Above is the code.

Input:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Output:

```
14
```

Expected output:

```
15
```

Comment: Does it not rather skip the *first* element (not the *last* element)?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the first input.
This will work.
But I dont understand what you want. So... I'll edit it when you say it's wrong and how I need to do it.

```
s = input()
s = s.split()
sum = 0

for i in range(0, len(s) - 1):
    if s[i] = s[i + 1]
    sum += int(i)
print(sum)
```